# How to hide value 0 of drop-down list in display

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

My Dropdownlist has value `0` → `---Please Select Flavor---`, and `1` → `Red velvet`

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="Flavorddlist" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="0">--- Please Select Flavor --</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Red Velvet</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

```cs
lblFlavor.Text = Flavorddlist.SelectedItem.Text;
```

The display should be:

**Flavor:** `---Please Select Flavor---`

if I choose the value `0`.

When I click the display button, I don't want it to display the value `0`. How can I hide the display when the dropdown's value is `0`?

I don't want to hide it in Dropdown list, I just want to hide it in the display once a value is chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the display when the selected value is 0 ("--- Please Select Flavor ---"), you can add a conditional check in your C# code before setting the lblFlavor.Text. If the selected value is 0, you can set the lblFlavor.Text to an empty string, effectively hiding the display.

```
if (Flavorddlist.SelectedValue == "0")
{
    lblFlavor.Text = ""; // Hide the display when the selected value is 0
}
else
{
    lblFlavor.Text = Flavorddlist.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```